# nested object in jsx to avoid error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
<input disabled={album.photos.length <= this.state.max} type='text' />
```

above code is prune to bug because what if album.photos is an empty array? How to solve this kind of issue without writing extra checking outside of jsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always check for the validity of any JS object|array before trying to get its value.

```
<input 
   disabled={(album.photos && album.photos.length <= this.state.max)} 
   type='text' 
/>
```

(album.photos) will check if the key 'photos' of album is defined or not.

Comment: If album.photos is not defined the result won't be a boolean, but will be `undefined`. In javascript `undefined !== false` and `undefined != false` , so *be careful*

Answer (score 0):

Validating it without writing anything out the JSX, comes to a couple of solutions:

```
<input 
    disabled={
        album.photos ?
            (album.photos.length <= this.state.max) : 
            false
    }
    type='text' />
```

Above solution solves your problem and efficient enough to maintain your concern with validations outer to the JSX.

Comment: Talking in efficiency as well as elegance of the code snippet conditional statement like this ( condition? true : false ) is more efficient than && operator. It also gives you to program a false case logic. Cutting it short it is a best practice both in efficiency and elegance.

Comment: @HaiderAliAnjum i dont agree with you. can you explain your idea how its more efficient than && operator ?